# d3.js bar chart with target lines

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

How can I build a bar chart with target lines in D3? I tried adding a line with the Target field on top of the bars but what I am trying to achieve is something similar to this:

[image]

This is my table:

```
Country,Nitrogen2012,Target
Poland,0.22,0.213
Sweden,0.13,0.156
Russia,0.11,0.097
Finland,0.11,0.110
Latvia,0.08,0.076
Atmospheric,0.08,0.075
Germany,0.07,0.075
Denmark,0.07,0.088
Lithuania,0.06,0.050
Estonia,0.03,0.033
Shipping,0.02,0.003
```

The code for the bar chart is this:

```js
 var margin = {
     top: 20,
     right: 20,
     bottom: 30,
     left: 80
   },
   width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right,
   height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

 var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");

 var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
   .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

 var y = d3.scale.linear()
   .range([height, 0]);

 var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
   .scale(x)
   .orient("bottom")
   .tickSize(-1);

 var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
   .scale(y)
   .orient("left")
   .ticks(2, "d")
   .tickSize(-1)
   .tickFormat(formatPercent);

 var tip = d3.tip()
   .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
   .offset([-10, 0])
   .html(function(d) {
     return "<strong>Average normalized input:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.Nitrogen2012 * 100 + "</span>";
   })

 var chart1 = d3.select("#graph1").append("svg")
   .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
   .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
   .append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

 chart1.call(tip);

 d3.csv("Nitrogen_Inputs2012ComparedToTarget.csv", type, function(error, data) {
   x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
     return d.Country;
   }));
   //x2.domain(data.map(function(d){return d.Target}));
   y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
     return d.Nitrogen2012
   })]);

   chart1.append("g")
     .attr("class", "x axis")
     .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
     .call(xAxis);

   chart1.append("g")
     .attr("class", "y axis")
     .call(yAxis);

   chart1.selectAll(".bar")
     .data(data)
     .enter().append("rect")
     .attr("class", "bar")
     .attr("x", function(d) {
       return x(d.Country);
     })
     .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
     .attr("y", function(d) {
       return y(d.Nitrogen2012);
     })
     .attr("height", function(d) {
       return height - y(d.Nitrogen2012);
     })
     .on('mouseover', tip.show)
     .on('mouseout', tip.hide);

 });

 function type(d) {
   d.Nitrogen2012 = +d.Nitrogen2012;
   return d;
 }
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your enter selection, add the line.  You could do this with `svg:line`, but I prefer building a `path`:

```
var eSel = chart1.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter();

eSel.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
 ...

 eSel.append("path")
    .style("stroke", "blue")
    .style("stroke-width", 2)
    .attr("d", function(d){
      var rv = "M" + x(d.Country) + "," + y(d.Target); // move to
      rv += "L" + (x(d.Country) + x.rangeBand()) + "," + y(d.Target); // line
      return rv;
    });
```

Working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/64nNNt3aHZ17dqn3o4jX?p=preview).

Comment: Absolutely great! Thanks!!